# Count if statement excluding strings and not equal to a number in excel

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I have an excel set for which I need to count entries based on names. They're all in the same column and there is supposed to be 4 of each entry. I need a formula to count the number of cells with the same entry that do NOT start with either "Retail" or "Commercial"  and only return the names in the cells for which there is NOT 4. For example, if my data looks thusly:

```
    NAME
Retail - John
Retail - Sue
Kara
Kara
Joe
Joe
Joe
Joe
Commercial
Sarah
```

I want a formula that will search this column, and only return "Kara - 2" and "Sarah - 1". The "Retail" and "Commercial" are excluded from the start and since "Joe"=4 I'm not concerned with that. Is there some way I can have this search the column, have it return the first count to meet that criteria to C1, the next one to C2 and so on until I have a column of just the non-compliant entries? I'd love an output like below:

```
NAME        COUNT
Kara          2
Sarah         1
```

Thanks for looking, I really appreciate any help and advice you can offer!

Comment: You may want to consider a pivot table to get a list of unique entries  and their counts, combined with a filter on a helper column (that refers to the column counts) that excludes the entries with the words "Retail" or "Commercial" in them as well those with a count less than 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in column A the results table will be in columns B & C after running this macro:

```
Sub MAIN()

Dim A As Range, wf As WorksheetFunction
Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
Dim col As Collection
Set A = Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set col = MakeColl(A)

s1 = "Retail"
s2 = "Commercial"
K = 1
For i = 1 To col.Count
    v = col.Item(i)
    If InStr(v, s1) = 0 And InStr(v, s2) = 0 Then
        n = wf.CountIf(A, v)
        If n <> 4 Then
            Cells(K, "B").Value = v
            Cells(K, "C").Value = n
            K = K + 1
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Public Function MakeColl(rng As Range) As Collection
    Set MakeColl = New Collection
    Dim r As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Value
        If v <> "" Then
            MakeColl.Add v, CStr(v)
        End If
    Next r
    MsgBox MakeColl.Count
End Function
```